# Is it possible to create a shortcut that represents every file in a directory

Tags: shortcut, alias

Is it possible to create a shortcut

```
ln -s ./source ./destination
```

that represents every file in a directory? I know I could just create an alias for the parent directory, but in my situation, I have to have an alias for each file. It would be prettier if I could create one alias that represented every file in a directory, rather than a whole bunch of them.

The syntax, I imagine would be something like this:

```
ln -s ./source/* ./destination
```

But of course that doesn't do anything.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/633605/how-to-create-symbolic-links-to-all-files-class-of-files-in-a-directory

Comment: Thanks, I tried searching for the answer, but looks like I gave up too soon.

Comment: @klanomath, on second comment, however, I'm looking to create one symlink for a set of files, not one symlink per file. So I'm actually looking for something different than that link.

Comment: A soft link is a file which contains **one** path to another target file or directory as data. A 1:n relation in a symlink doesn't make much sense in a hierarchical file system!

Comment: Well, what I'm asking is most likely impossible then :D, I guess I was looking to create the impression of a directory but have the function as if the files were in the parent (why would I want this? Because the program requires it to be this way, I was just trying to separate the program files from my own).In this case, the files are game required assets and game mods additions. They share the same folder and there are hundreds of the original game files that I try to sort through when swapping out mods. Thanks for trying to help anyway though.